# Changing Main image from Thumb image on mouseover using JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have an issue at the moment. I am trying to build a single page web application using jQuery, JSON Bootstrap.

Up to now, I have created a category page, a product selection page, and a item page.

My issue is on the item page, where the user selects option for sizes etc, the user should be able to on mouse over or click - to change the smaller thumb images to the larger image.

For context, I will post a code snippet of my JSON object, and my current code to apply the new elements to the DOM. I will also show a picture of the product page where the user may hover or click on the thumbnail images to then change the src depending on the image selected.

An example of the JSON object:

```
 {
                        "productTitle": "NIKE HYPERKO 2.0 BOXING BOOTS",
                        "productBrand": "NIKE",
                        "productDescription": "",
                        "productImg": "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
                        "smallImages": [
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/21032253.jpg",
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/aps-5704.jpg"
                        ],
                        "largeImages": [
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/21032253.jpg",
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
                            "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/aps-5704.jpg"
                        ],
                        "productCode": "BA8810",
                        "discountPercentage": "",
                        "stockAvailability": "IN STOCK",
                        "productColour": "Black/Gold",
                        "sizesAvailable": [
                            6,
                            7,
                            8,
                            9,
                            10,
                            11
                        ],
                        "productPrice": 124.99
                    },
```

[image: This image is what is created from my JSON using jQuery]

The code for generating the item based on the product selected on the previous screen is:

```
function showItem(product) {
    console.table(product);
    let container = $('#item-container');
    container.html('');
    container.addClass('bg-white pt-2 rounded');

    let imageContainer = $('<div class="col-md-5">');
    let image = $('<img src="' + product.productImg + '">').addClass('p-3').attr({
        'id': "mainProductImage",
        'height': '75%',
        'width': '100%',
    });

    let informationContainer = $('<div class="col-md-7">')

    let title = $('<p>').html('Name: ' + product.productTitle);
    let brand = $('<p>').html('Brand: ' + product.productBrand);
    let stockStatus = $('<p>').html('Stock: ' + product.stockAvailability);
    let description = $('<p>').html('Description: ' + product.productDescription);
    let price = $('<p>').html('Price: £' + product.productPrice);
    let splitter = $('</hr>').addClass('border-dark');
    let sizeLabel = $('<p id="selectSize">').html('Select size:');
    let dropdown = $('<select>').addClass('form-control').attr({
        'id': 'quantitySelect'
    });
    let smallImage = $('<div>').attr({
        "width": "100%",
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "space-between"
    });


    let buyBtn = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-dark btn-block mt-2').attr({
        'type': 'button',
        'value': 'Add to cart',
    }).html('Add to cart');


    container.append(imageContainer);
    container.append(informationContainer);
    imageContainer.append(image);
    imageContainer.append(smallImage);


    informationContainer.append(title);
    informationContainer.append(brand);
    informationContainer.append(stockStatus);
    informationContainer.append(price);
    informationContainer.append(description);
    informationContainer.append(splitter);


    if (product.sizesAvailable.length > 0) {
        informationContainer.append(sizeLabel);
        informationContainer.append(dropdown);
        product.sizesAvailable.forEach((size) => {

            let dropdownItem = $('<option>').attr({
                'value': size
            }).html(size);
            dropdown.append(dropdownItem);
        });
    }
    if (product.smallImages.length > 0) {
        product.smallImages.forEach((image) => {
            let thumbImage = $('<img src="' + image + '">').attr({
                'width': '90px',
                'height': 'auto',
                'cursor': 'pointer'
                 
            });
            smallImage.append(thumbImage);
            smallImage.on('click', () => {
               // console.log($(this)[0].getAttribute('src'));
                
                // $('#mainProductImage').prop('src') = smallImage.prop('src');   //This line here needs a look at...
            })
        });
    }
```

The last few lines of the code posted above, is my issue. I am struggling with changing the src of the main image using the "largeImages" in the JSON from mouse click on "smallImages" in the JSON.

I would be seriously grateful for anyone who could possibly help me on the right path!

Any questions about the code, I would be more than happy to answer.

Again thank you!

Comment: Hi, there are many such products or only 1 and all have there large images ?

Comment: @Swati Hi, there are many different products and categories. Footwear, Gloves, Clothing etc... Each with the same layout of objects that are iterated through and appended to the dom using forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there many such products in your page you need to use `class` here because multiple elements cannot have same `id`. Then, whenever your small image is clicked get the `index()` of the images and also the `title` of product this will help us to get only *JSON Object* where title is same . Now, just use `.attr("src","newimages")` to set new src for your main product image

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var product = {
  "productTitle": "NIKE HYPERKO 2.0 BOXING BOOTS",
  "productBrand": "NIKE",
  "productDescription": "",
  "productImg": "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
  "smallImages": [
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/21032253.jpg",
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/72x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/aps-5704.jpg"
  ],
  "largeImages": [
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/21032253.jpg",
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/i/ci2953-606b.jpg",
    "https://www.boxfituk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/500x500/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/p/aps-5704.jpg"
  ]
}
showItem(product)

function showItem(product) {
  console.table(product);
  //use class
  let container = $('.item-container');
  container.html('');
  container.addClass('bg-white pt-2 rounded');

  let imageContainer = $('<div class="col-md-5">');
  let image = $('<img src="' + product.productImg + '">').addClass('p-3').attr({
    'class': "mainProductImage", //give class here
    'height': '75%',
    'width': '100%',
  });

  let informationContainer = $('<div class="col-md-7">')
  //use class here as well
  let title = $('<p>').html('Name: <span class="title">' + product.productTitle + '</span>');
  let smallImage = $('<div>').attr({
    "width": "100%",
    "display": "flex",
    "justify-content": "space-between",
    "class": "small_images" //add class here 
  });
  container.append(imageContainer);
  container.append(informationContainer);
  imageContainer.append(image);
  imageContainer.append(smallImage);
  informationContainer.append(title);
  if (product.smallImages.length > 0) {
    product.smallImages.forEach((image) => {
      let thumbImage = $('<img src="' + image + '">').attr({
        'width': '90px',
        'height': 'auto',
        'cursor': 'pointer'

      });
      smallImage.append(thumbImage);
    });
  }
}
//onclick of small images
$(document).on("click", ".small_images img", function() {
  //get title of the product
  var product_title = $(this).closest(".item-container").find(".title").text();
  var index = $(this).index() //get index of images 0,1,2
  //filter your jsons datas to return only json where title matches because there will be many products
  var large_img = $(product)
    .filter(function(i, n) {
      return n.productTitle === product_title;
    });
  //get closet outer div and set src of main image inside it
  $(this).closest('.item-container').find('.mainProductImage').attr('src', large_img[0].largeImages[index])

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-container"></div>
```